Parabolicity of the universal cover
A Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is said to be parabolic if it does not admit a positive Green function. There are also equivalent definition such as:

A manifold $M$ is parabolic iff any positive superharmonic function on $M$ is constant.

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a noncompact Riemannian manifold with nonnegative Ricci curvature. Let $\pi:\bar{M}\rightarrow M$ is the projection map from the universal cover $\bar{M}$ to $M$. $\bar{M}$ is equipped with the pull-back metric $\pi^*g$. If $(M,g)$ is parabolic, is there any possibility that $\bar{M}$ with the metric $\pi^*g$ is also parabolic?
